# python tkinter - interactive plot and listbox with span widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Following steps i try to do:
1. insert a list of value pairs [xmin, xmax]
2. create a initial list of span objects
3. plot the spans and write the labels into a listbox
4. add spans to plot (via onlick event) and update the listbox
5. remove and higlight spans

Here is a sample code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

class App:
     def __init__(self, master, l_val_pair):
         # Create a container
         frame = tk.Frame(master)

         # Create fields
         self.button_left = tk.Button(frame,text="Export")
         self.button_left.pack(side="left")
         self.button_right = tk.Button(frame,text="Delete", command = 
                                       lambda: self.delete(self.l_spans))
         self.button_right.pack(side="left")

         self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
         self.listbox.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X) 

         #define figure
         self.fig = Figure()
         self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

         #sample data for a line
         self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
         self.y = np.sin(2*np.pi*self.x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(self.x))

         #plot line and list of spans
         self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)

         self.l_spans = [self.ax.axes.axvspan(
                 val_pair[0],val_pair[1], facecolor='red', alpha=0.3, label=val_pair) 
                    for val_pair in l_val_pair]

         #create a listbox      
         [self.listbox.insert(tk.END, item.get_label()) for item in self.l_spans]
         self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.highlight_span)         

         #plot figure
         self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
         self.canvas.show()
         self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
         frame.pack()

         #use span selector
         self.span = SpanSelector(self.ax, self.sel_span, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                             rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'), span_stays=False)

         #connect
         self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.span)


     def sel_span(self,xmin, xmax):
         indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax))
         indmax = min(len(self.x) - 1, indmax)

         span = self.ax.axes.axvspan(xmin=self.x[indmin], xmax=self.x[indmax], 
                              alpha = 0.5, facecolor='red')

         #add actual span to list of spans
         self.l_spans.append(span)

         #update view (spans and listbox) with central list of spans          
         self.update_view()


     def update_view(self):
         #clear visualisation
         self.listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
         [span.remove() for span in self.l_spans]


         #fill with new data
         [self.listbox.insert(tk.END, span.get_label()) for span in self.l_spans]
         [span.draw(self.ax) for span in self.l_spans] #HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!

         #update view
         #...


     def highlight_span():
         pass

     def delete(self,item):
         pass

list_vals= [[1,2],[2.5,4]]
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, list_vals)
root.mainloop()
```

Problem in function update_view:
What is that renderer i need to insert into span.draw()?

I'm unsure if my approach is good as I have no experience with tkinter. What do you think?

Comment: You wouldn't draw the spans alone. There is a lot more in the canvas to draw. Hence you will want to draw the whole canvas, `self.canvas.draw_idle()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your code a bit, removing the `update_view` method that was (in my opinion) not strictly necessary. I've added all the relevant content in the `sel_span` method, which is called every time you select an area in the graph.

I've also created another method `remove_spans` to remove the selected area and clear the listbox below. This I've also bound to the `Delete` button, so that if the button is pressed the selection and the textbox are cleared.

I've also removed the binding of the listbox to the `ListboxSelect` event, as the listbox will be updated when the `insert` method is called.

Last: I've added your `xmin` and `xmax` values to the listbox, instead of the `span.get_label()` items. Here is the example code:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master, l_val_pair):
         # Create a container
        frame = tk.Frame(master)

        # Create fields
        self.button_left = tk.Button(frame,text="Export")
        self.button_left.pack(side="left")
        self.button_right = tk.Button(frame,text="Delete", command = self.remove_spans)
        self.button_right.pack(side="left")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
        self.listbox.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X) 

        #define figure
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        #sample data for a line
        self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
        self.y = np.sin(2*np.pi*self.x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(self.x))

        #plot line and list of spans
        self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)

        self.l_spans = [self.ax.axes.axvspan(val_pair[0],val_pair[1], facecolor='red', alpha=0.3, label=val_pair) 
                    for val_pair in l_val_pair]

        #create a listbox      
        [self.listbox.insert(tk.END, item.get_label()) for item in self.l_spans]          

        #plot figure
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.pack()

        #use span selector
        self.span = SpanSelector(self.ax, self.sel_span, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                             rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'), span_stays=False)

        #connect
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.span)


    def sel_span(self, xmin, xmax):
        #clear visualisation
        self.remove_spans()
        indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax))
        indmax = min(len(self.x) - 1, indmax)
        span = self.ax.axes.axvspan(xmin=self.x[indmin], xmax=self.x[indmax], 
                              alpha = 0.5, facecolor='red')

        #add actual span to list of spans
        self.l_spans.append(span)

        #for span in self.l_spans:
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, xmin)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, xmax)


    def remove_spans(self):
        self.listbox.delete(0,tk.END)

        for span in self.l_spans:
           try:
               span.remove()
           except:
               pass
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


list_vals= [[1,2],[2.5,4]]
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, list_vals)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
The comment clarified the use case a bit more, so here is a modified version of the code. I re-introduced the binding to the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event and written the `highlight_span` method that:

- Checks which range in the list has been selected
- highlights it in the figure in green (just to make it more visible)

I've also changed the code so that old selections are not deleted from the listbox:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import ast

class App:
    def __init__(self, master, l_val_pair):
         # Create a container
        frame = tk.Frame(master)

        # Create fields
        self.button_left = tk.Button(frame,text="Export")
        self.button_left.pack(side="left")
        self.button_right = tk.Button(frame,text="Delete", command = self.remove_spans)
        self.button_right.pack(side="left")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
        self.listbox.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X) 
        self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.highlight_span)   

        #define figure
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        #sample data for a line
        self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
        self.y = np.sin(2*np.pi*self.x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(self.x))

        #plot line and list of spans
        self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)

        self.l_spans = [self.ax.axes.axvspan(val_pair[0],val_pair[1], facecolor='red', alpha=0.3, label=val_pair) 
                    for val_pair in l_val_pair]

        #create a listbox      
        [self.listbox.insert(tk.END, item.get_label()) for item in self.l_spans]

        #plot figure
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.pack()

        #use span selector
        self.span = SpanSelector(self.ax, self.sel_span, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                             rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'), span_stays=False)

        #connect
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.span)


    def sel_span(self, xmin, xmax):
        #clear visualisation        
        for span in self.l_spans:
           try:
               span.remove()
           except:
               pass
        self.canvas.draw_idle()        

        indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax))
        indmax = min(len(self.x) - 1, indmax)
        span = self.ax.axes.axvspan(xmin=self.x[indmin], 
                                    xmax=self.x[indmax], 
                                    alpha = 0.5,  
                                    facecolor='red',
                                    label = [xmin, xmax])

        #add actual span to list of spans
        self.l_spans.append(span)

        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, span.get_label())        


    def remove_spans(self):
        self.listbox.delete(0,tk.END)

        for span in self.l_spans:
           try:
               span.remove()
           except:
               pass
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def highlight_span(self, evt):        
        w = evt.widget
        index = w.curselection()[0]
        value = w.get(index)
        value = list(map(float, ast.literal_eval(value)))

        xmin = value[0]
        xmax = value[1]

        indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax))
        indmax = min(len(self.x) - 1, indmax)
        span = self.ax.axes.axvspan(xmin=self.x[indmin], 
                                    xmax=self.x[indmax], 
                                    alpha = 0.5,  
                                    facecolor='green',
                                    label = [xmin, xmax])
        self.l_spans.append(span)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()



list_vals= [[1,2],[2.5,4]]
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, list_vals)
root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is a bit more complicated. A new span should be added to the list and the plot by the interactive drag. If you select a span in the list, it should be highlighted in a darker or different color. The deletion should remove the span from the list box and the plot. All others should be preserved.

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to add the span re-drawn in the `highlight_span` method...I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. But one question will not let me go. Why can not the span object be addressed directly? Like span.set_alpha=1, span. show() for highlight.

Comment: You mean in case you want to change the `alpha` value? You can, I've just tried and it works...but maybe I didn't get your point...

Comment: I edited the initial post. Maybe u will understand what i mean. I just want to change the transperency of the span object temporarily.

Comment: I see, but every time you use the selector you delete the list of spans (`span.remove()`), so you need to re-add it. You just keep its limits in the listbox, but the actual `span` object is gone.

Comment: I removed this (span.remove()) in my actual version. But it does not work anyway. I do not get an error message. Is there a documentation for the axvpan object?

Comment: One important thing is the conversion of the value you get back from the widget, it's unicode and you should use the `ast.literal_eval` method to convert them to `float`...